ngxDaterangepickerMd is not visible after migrating to MDC-based Angular Material Components
I am using also ngx-daterangepicker-material library, and I have updated with angular material v15 from legacy components to MDC components. After this migration the date picker is no longer visible, or it does not work.
I have tried adding appearance="outline" in the mat-form-field and at least it is visible but underneath everything. Even so I don't want it to be outline, but without adding an appearance o with appearance="fill" it does not appear.
<mat-form-field>
        <mat-label></mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="Date" ngxDaterangepickerMd [(ngModel)]="initialDates"
            [locale]="locale" [ranges]="ranges" [minDate]="minDate" [alwaysShowCalendars]="true" [autoApply]="true"
            [showDropdowns]="true" [showWeekNumbers]="true" opens="center" [linkedCalendars]="false" readonly="true"
            (rangeClicked)="rangeClicked($event)" (startDateChanged)="setStart($event)"
            (endDateChanged)="setEnd($event)" (datesUpdated)="onClose()"/>
</mat-form-field>

I have also tried adding the following rule:
input.mat-mdc-input-element::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
   display: block !important;
}

In addition to this one which is the one suggested in the migration guide:
.mdc-text-field__input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: block !important;
}


Move ngxDaterangepickerMd input outside of mat-form-field.

For stand alone components, the dependency injectors hierarchy is more different.
If any of your third party library (in your case ngx-daterangepicker-material) offers only an NgModule API for its DI configurations then you have to configure your Stand-alone component to import the new module which in turn need to update with required providers or modules.
When Angular creates a standalone component, it needs to know that the current injector has all the necessary services for the standalone component's dependencies, including those based on NgModules. To guarantee that, in some cases Angular will create a new "standalone injector" as a child of the current environment injector. Today, this happens for all bootstrapped standalone components: it will be a child of the root environment injector.
// DateRangeModule 

    import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
    import { DatePickerComponent } from "./date-picker.component";
    import { NgxDaterangepickerMd } from "ngx-daterangepicker-material";
    import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
    import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
    
    @NgModule({
        declarations: [DatePickerComponent],
        imports: [
            FormsModule,
            CommonModule,
            NgxDaterangepickerMd.forRoot()
        ],
        exports: [DatePickerComponent],
        providers: [],
    })
    export class DateRangeModule {
    }

// DateRangeComponent 

    import { Component } from "@angular/core";
    import { DateRangeModule } from "./date-range.module";
    
    @Component({
        selector: 'date-range',
        template: '<datepicker></datepicker>',
        standalone: true,
        imports: [DateRangeModule]
    })
    export class DateRangeComponent {
    }



   //DatePickerComponent 
    
    import { Component } from "@angular/core";
    import dayjs, { Dayjs } from "dayjs";
    
        @Component({
            selector: 'datepicker',
            template: '<input type="text" ngxDaterangepickerMd [(ngModel)]="selected" class="form-control"/>',
        })
        export class DatePickerComponent {
            selected: {start: Dayjs, end: Dayjs};
        constructor() {
            this.selected = {
                start: dayjs('09/09/2023'),
                end: dayjs('09/10/2023')
            };
        }
        }

use date-range selector wherever required - this will populate the date-range-picker of ngx-daterangepicker-material.
